# ImplicitRegion vs DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I've been having troubles with numerical integration over implicit regions, so I checked in a simple example if the result coincides with integrating with a DiracDelta function, and found this rather puzzling behaviour:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[1 - x y] x^3 y^4, {x, 1/2, ∞}, {y, 1/2, ∞}]
```

> 3/2

and :

```
Integrate[
     x^3 y^4, 
     {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[{1 == x y, x > 1/2, y > 1/2}, {x, y}]
] // TrigToExp // Simplify  
% // N
```

> Log[2] + 1/8 (3 Sqrt[17] - 4 Log[1 + Sqrt[17]] + 4 Log[4 + Sqrt[17]])
>
> 2.46979

It doesn't look like `ImplicitRegion` would just be "forgetting" a Jacobian which would be $1/x$ or $1/y$ depending on the strategy anyway, not resulting in a crazy `Log[1+Sqrt[17]]` etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90692/discussion-on-question-by-picop-implicitregion-vs-diracdelta).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relavant mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any discrepancy here. The region integration is performed over a curve, and one needs to include the arc length measure. For example, the following:

```
Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[{1 == x y, x > 1/2, y > 1/2}, {x, y}]] //TeXForm
```

> $2 (-1)^{3/4} \left(F\left(\left.\csc ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)-E\left(\left.\csc ^{-1}\left(2
>    \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)+F\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)-E\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(2
>    \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$

should measure the arc length of the implicit region. This agrees with:

```
ArcLength @ ImplicitRegion[{1 == x y, x > 1/2, y > 1/2}, {x, y}] //TeXForm
```

> $2 (-1)^{3/4} \left(F\left(\left.\csc ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)-E\left(\left.\csc ^{-1}\left(2
>    \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)+F\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)-E\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(2
>    \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$

For your example, Mathematica returns:

```
Integrate[x^3 y^4, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[{1 == x y, x > 1/2, y > 1/2}, {x, y}]]
```

> 1/8 (3 Sqrt[17] - 4 ArcCsch[4] + 4 ArcSinh[4])

Doing the integral by "hand" (including the arc length factor $\sqrt{1 + y'(x)^2}$):

```
Integrate[x^3 (1/x)^4 Sqrt[1 + D[1/x, x]^2], {x, 1/2, 2}]
```

> 1/8 (3 Sqrt[17] - 4 ArcSinh[1/4] + 4 ArcSinh[4])

agrees with the Mathematica result.

Comment: How is this related to DiracDelta? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 I thought the DiracDelta integration was straightforward and needed no explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\frac{1}{8} \left(3 \sqrt{17}+4 \sinh ^{-1}(4)-4 \text{csch}^{-1}(4)\right) \neq \frac 3 2$.

Comment: @user64494 The region integration is not equivalent to a similar integral with a dirac delta function, so there is no reason for them to be equal. Basically, the dirac integral does not have the arc length factor.

Comment: Thank you. Therefore, the question is unclear.